# Regular or context-free or other

Tags: regular-language, formal-languages, context-free-language

I have a problem that needs to find out the following language is regular or context-free or other.
{a^(2i+3j) | i>0, j>0}

I have some doubts to say it is a regular or context-free language because it has no pattern.

Comment: All the sentences consist only of `a`s. Now, which sentences consisting only of `a`s are not in the language? Maybe you can see a pattern...

Answer (score 0):

The strings in the language are the following:

1. a^5 = aaaaa is in the language, choosing i = j = 1
2. a^7 = aaaaaaa is in the language, choosing i = 2, j = 1
3. a^8 = aaaaaaaa is in the language, choosing i = 1 and j = 2
4. a^k is in the language for all k > 8

- assume k is even. then choose j = 2 and choose i = (k - 6) / 2
- assume k is odd. then choose j = 1 and choose i = (k - 3) / 2

The only strings not in the language are the following:

```
L' = {e, a, aa, aaa, aaaa, aaaaaa}
```

The complement of our language is finite, thus regular; and by closure properties we know our language must be regular, since the complement of a regular language is regular.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this by constructing the automata. Doing this with a non-deterministic automata is easier, so that will be a more general solution.

*NFA*

**Non-deterministic** finite automata are equivalent to DFAs and regular languages.

To construct such automata, you simply concatenate an automata that has to see an even,non zero number of `a`s to an automata that has to see a multiply of 3 times number of `a`s, keeping only the last step of the latter as accepting.

Basically, the non-determinism of moving between those 2 automatas (and staying at the first one) is checking whether the number of `a`s can be expressed as `2i+3j`.

*Specific solution*

A more specific solution, would use the fact that the `gcd(2,3)=1`, which means that there's some `N=6` so that for any `n>N` this automata will accept.

We also note that we can accept `n=5`. We can now construct a DFA that after getting 6 `a`s has a "sink" state that accepts.